# Android : Create a single task with multiple applications' activities (Lauchmode issue)

Tags: android, android-intent, android-pendingintent, aidl, launchmode

I don't know how to tackle this Android issue.  In few words, the flow between my 2 applications is as below :

### Flow

1. Bind **Application A** to a service in **Market application** (AIDL)
2. **Register a BroadcastReceiver** and call a service method that **returns a pendingIntent**.
3. **Launch PendingIntent** (contains BillingActivity instance).
4. Start PaymentActivity with "**startActivityForResult()**".
5. Do some stuffs, **terminate** (finish() ).
6. in **onActivitiyResult()** method, **send a Broadcast** and terminate.
7. **Get Broadcast informations**.

[image: Flow between my 2 applications]

### Issue :

I want to create a **task** with the below components :

- Top1Activity(Application A)
- BillingActivity (Market Application)
- PaymentActivity (Market Application)

[image: foreground and background tasks for Android]

I tried to change the **BillingActivity** + **PaymentActivity** "launchMode" :

> singleInstance

A new task is created for both of them. When pressing return button (or calling finish() method), user is redirected as expected to the previous activity. Problem: **"StartActivityForResult" cannot be use between multiple tasks** (onActivityResult is called immediately ).

> SingleTask

When pressing return button (or calling finish() method) in BillingActivity, **user is redirected to the Top2Activity** (which was in the background task).

I 've lost more than 48 hours trying to solve it. I would appreciate your help.
I can post code if needed.

Thank you

----------- EDIT 2015-02-02

Following the advice of David, i removed all special launch modes :

**TOP2Activity(background):**

```
<activity
    android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustPan" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.app.searchable"
        android:resource="@xml/searchable" />

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <data android:scheme="xxx" />
        <data android:host="xxx" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

**My Top1Activity(Foreground):**

```
<activity
    android:name="activities.MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

**BillingActivity(Foreground):**

```
<activity
    android:name=".activities.BillingActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
    android:excludeFromRecents="true"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_billing"

    android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

**PaymentActivity:**

```
<activity
    android:name=".activities.PaymentActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_payment"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"

    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" >
</activity>
```

**AIDL Service returning pendingIntent:**

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClass(InBillingService.this, jp.xxx.activities.BillingActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(Consts.PENDING_INTENT_INFO, result);
intent.putExtra(Consts.RESULT_KEY, nextSession);


PendingIntent pendingIntent;                    
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(InBillingService.this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

bundle.putParcelable(Consts.PENDING_INTENT, pendingIntent);
```

When pressing back button from BillingActivity (or PaymentActivity), **I am still redirected to the Top2Activity**...

No idea ?
Thank you

Comment: Doesn't look like you need anything special. Remove all special launch modes. If it doesn't work as you expect, please explain what happens.

Comment: Thank you David. I have updated my message (adding some code). I've changed my launch modes as you told me but it didn't fix it. no idea ? thank you

Comment: Please explain what is `Top2Activity` and post the manifest for that. and indicate how it got in the task. It sounds like your problem is `taskAffinity`

Comment: Top2Activity is the main activity(after the splash screen) for  my "Market application". This is the last activity displayed before application A is launched. manifest info is available in my message. If you need more details, please let me know. thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `android:taskAffinity=""` to the `<activity> defninitions for both`BillingActivity`and`PaymentActivity`.